# A picture or the picture; mood or moods?

Tags: word-usage, articles

I am about to send this message to my group mates:

> I am sending you the picture of my wholesome dad to elevate your moods!

Should I say 'a picture' or 'the picture'? Is is better to use mood or moods?

Comment: wholesome is not great there...that said, a picture of

Answer (score 0):

If there had been previous discussion that identified a specific picture, then it should be "the" picture. But if it might be any of the many possible pictures of your dad, then use "a picture". Either "mood" or "moods" could be used here, but I think "mood" sounds more natural.